# tweepyを使って、特定のツイートに対してリツイートしたユーザーidを全件取得する方法はありますか？

Tags: python, twitter

はじめまして。
現在、データ分析に関する内容としてpythonのtweepy(3.9.0)を使用してデータを取得しようと思っております。
そこで質問です。タイトルにもある通り、特定のツイートに対してリツイートしたユーザーidを全件取得する方法を知りたいです。全件です。リツイートの数が1000件あれば、1000件のユーザーidを取得したいです。ユーザーid自体はとってこれるのですが、全件取得ができません。以下、試したコードです。

```
import tweepy

CONSUMER_KEY    = '〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕'
ACCESS_TOKEN    = '〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET   = '✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕✕'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

retweeters1 = tweepy.Cursor(api.retweeters, id=1234567890).Items()
retweeters2 = api.retweeters(id=1234567890, cursor= -1)
```

retweetwer1も2も全件取得は出来なかったです。どのようなコードを書けば全件取得できるか教えていただきたいです。
また、Cursorの意味についてもあまり理解できなかったので、併せて教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

ブラウザでアクセスした時も同様ですが、結果が一定以上ある場合にはページ分割がされると思います。
今回のようにすべての結果を取得したい場合には、`for` ループなどを使って繰り返し処理する方法が考えられます。

以下のページのコードスニペットにはいくつかのサンプルが載せてあるので、これらが参考になるんじゃないかと思います (私自身は普段 Python を書かないので、サンプルそのままの紹介に留めます)。

[コードスニペット — tweepy 3.6.0 ドキュメント](https://kurozumi.github.io/tweepy/code_snippet.html#followall)

> このスニペットは、認証されたユーザーのすべてのフォロワーをフォローします。
>
> ```
> for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items():
>     follower.follow()
> ```

また、"Cursor" については以下の説明が参考になるかと。

[カーソルのチュートリアル — tweepy 3.6.0 ドキュメント](https://kurozumi.github.io/tweepy/cursor_tutorial.html)

> Twitter APIの開発では、ページネーションを多く使用しています。タイムライン、ユーザリスト、ダイレクトメッセージなどを繰り返し処理するページングを実行するには、リクエストごとにページ/カーソルパラメータを指定する必要があります。ここでの問題は、ページネーションループを管理するために多くのボイラープレートコードが必要になることです。ページ番号を簡単にし、必要なコードを少なくするためにTweepyにはCursorオブジェクトがあります。

なお、前述のリンク先は有志による日本語訳となるので、必要に応じて (英語になりますが) [公式のドキュメント](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/) も参照してください。